# Ruby on Rails redirection order of operations problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def completed_offer
    redirect_to accepts_thankyou_path
    @checkout.destroy
end
```

Above is a redirection in Rails 4. I understand that the code below the redirect will continue which I am fine with. This is a checkout routine and I destroy @checkout at the end which is a "cart" with associated "cart_items". Below is the association which causes all the cart_items to be destroyed on a call to destroy a cart

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cart_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

Is there anyway to render a view before continuing the checkout routine so I can have access to the cart AND cart_items? I can't render and have to redirect because I don't want the user to keep resubmitting a post-data on a refresh.

Comment: This is a good case to use a background job to actually perform the cart clearing logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to do;

```
@cart = Cart.find('something')
@items = @cart.cart_items.to_a
@cart.destroy
```

In this way I had access to both @cart and @items for a single view